# Complex fraction

Tags: fractions

my book uses a technique to write fractions in a way that I am not familiar with.

How does $$\frac{\frac{1}{243}-1}{-\frac{2}{3}}$$
equate to $$\frac{3\left(1-\frac{1}{243}\right)}{2}$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Division means multiplication of the reciprocal, so $$(\frac1{243}-1)\div (-\frac23)\implies(\frac1{243}-1)\times(-\frac32).$$

As well, a binomial involving subtraction can be rewritten by *factoring out* a negative:  $$(a-b)=-(b-a).$$

Combining the two ideas, we have
\begin{align}
(\frac1{243}-1)\times(-\frac32)&=(1-\frac1{243})\times(\frac32)\\
&=\frac32\times(1-\frac1{243})\\
&=\frac{3(1-\frac1{243})}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Exactly the very last step I did not understand. I would assume your last step is a result of $$\frac{3}{2}*\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{243}\right)}{1}$$ , am I right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Any expression $x$ can be written _rationally_ as $\frac{x}1$.  Then you can proceed to multiply the numerators and denominators.

Comment: Although, I would argue that it would be simpler just to evaluate $1-\frac1{243}=\frac{242}{243}$ and take it from there.  I'm not sure why your book does not do this.

Answer (score 0):

The numerator and denominator of the fraction were multiplied by $-3$.  That clears the complex fraction in the denominator and inverts the binomial in the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

You multiply numerator and denominator both by $-3$ ("expand the fraction by a factor of $-3$"). This operation is well-known not to change the value of a fraction.